# Javascript - RegEx Uppercase and LowerCase and Mixed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
var cadena = prompt("Cadena:");

document.write(mayusminus(cadena));

function mayusminus(cad){
    var resultado = "Desconocido";

    if(cad.match(new RegExp("[A-Z]"))){
        resultado="mayúsculas";
    }else{
        if(cad.match(new RegExp("[a-z]"))){
            resultado="minúsculas";
        }else{
            if(cad.match(new RegExp("[a-zA-z]"))){
            resultado = "minúsculas y MAYUSCULAS";
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

I always have **mayusculas** or **minusculas**, never **minusculas y MAYUSCULAS** (MIXED), I am learning regexp and dont know my error yet :S

Comment: Please add the call of `mayusminus` to your question, including its parameters, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: you have a mistake in the last [a-zA-z] - it should be [a-zA-Z] in any case (pun intended)

Comment: Zeta you can read all the post and you see the call to mayusminus, and the expected result and actual result :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new RegExp("[A-Z]")
```

matches when *any* character in `cadena` is an upper-case letter.
To match when *all* characters are upper-case, use

```
new RegExp("^[A-Z]+$")
```

The `^` forces it to start at the start, the `$` forces it to end at the end and the `+` ensures that between the end there are one or more of `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand regex better now :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wanted to use regex patterns `^[a-z]+$`, `^[A-Z]+$` and `^[a-zA-Z]+$`.

In regex, the caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string. Similarly, `$` matches right after the last character in the string. Additionaly, `+` means *one or more occurrences*.

It is necessary to use `^` and `$` in the pattern, if you want to ensure no other then listed characters are in the string.

---

***JavaScript***:

```
s = 'tEst';
r = (s.match(new RegExp("^[a-z]+$")))    ? 'minúsculas' :
    (s.match(new RegExp("^[A-Z]+$")))    ? 'mayúsculas' :
    (s.match(new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$"))) ? 'minúsculas y mayúsculas' :
                                           'desconocido';
```

Test this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dv9N/).

Comment: Thanks! I understand regex better now :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say cad is `foo`:

```
// will return false
if (cad.match(new RegExp("[A-Z]"))) {
    resultado="mayúsculas";
// so will go there
} else {
    // will return true
    if (cad.match(new RegExp("[a-z]"))) {
        // so will go there
        resultado="minúsculas";
    } else {
        if (cad.match(new RegExp("[a-zA-z]"))) {
            resultado = "minúsculas y MAYUSCULAS";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say cad is `FOO`:

```
// will return true
if (cad.match(new RegExp("[A-Z]"))) {
    // so will go there
    resultado="mayúsculas";
} else {
    if (cad.match(new RegExp("[a-z]"))) {
        resultado="minúsculas";
    } else {
        if (cad.match(new RegExp("[a-zA-z]"))) {
            resultado = "minúsculas y MAYUSCULAS";
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, let's say cad is `FoO`:

```
// will return true
if (cad.match(new RegExp("[A-Z]"))) {
    // so will go there
    resultado="mayúsculas";
} else {
    if (cad.match(new RegExp("[a-z]"))) {
        resultado="minúsculas";
    } else {
        if(cad.match(new RegExp("[a-zA-z]"))) {
            resultado = "minúsculas y MAYUSCULAS";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the nested `else` is never visited.

What you can do is:

```
if (cad.match(new RegExp("^[A-Z]+$"))) {
    resultado="mayúsculas";
} else if (cad.match(new RegExp("^[a-z]+$"))) {
    resultado="minúsculas";
} else {
    resultado = "minúsculas y MAYUSCULAS";
}
```

Explanation:

`^` means *from the beginning of the string*,

`$` means *to the end of the string*,

`<anything>+` means *at least one anything*.

That said,

`^[A-Z]+$` means *the string should only contains uppercased chars*,

`^[a-z]+$` means *the string should only contains lowercased chars*.

So if the string isn't only composed by uppercased or lowercased chars, the string contains both of them.